# How would you add a number to every piece of data in a column in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

So if I have one column of data called credit_debt that has ten different numbers in it, and I wanted to add 100 to each of those, how would I do that? I know that I could do it manually one by one, but how would I do it all in one command?

Comment: you can use update ..  try a simple tutorial for  this sql statement

Comment: But wouldn't I have to do it one entry at a time like that?

Comment: No  .. the sql Update  is for all the rows that match the where condition .. is easy .. but try with simple tutorial  ..

Comment: This is what I was thinking too, but what if there is no where condition? There are just a bunch of random numbers in the column, and I need to add 100 to each of them. What would be there where condition in this case?

Comment: If there is not where condition you update all the rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update all of the rows in a table, we can issue an UPDATE statement without a WHERE clause.

We can reference the *current values* stored in columns in the UPDATE statement.

Assuming that `credit_debt` column is a *numeric* datatype (e.g. INT, DECIMAL, DOUBLE, et al.)

```
 UPDATE mytable 
    SET credit_debt = credit_debt + 100 
 ;
```

---

Before running an UPDATE like that, I always ensure that I have a good backup, and a way to restore to the current state. And I *test* my expressions in a SELECT, so I won't have to do a restore. Before running that UPDATE, I'd run a SELECT like this:

```
 SELECT credit_debt 
      , credit_debt + 100  AS _new_credit_debt
   FROM mytable
  ORDER BY ... 
 ;
```

And the verify that the value returned for _new_credit_debt is the value I want to assign to the column. (We can add whatever other expressions to the SELECT list we want, so we can verify the results.